# Symfony forms & json objects validation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create an object of type, say, `Slot` related to an object of other type, `Customer`. Here is how the post request body looks like.

```
  {
       "name: "foo
       "customer": {id: 21}
  }
```

here is how I get the data and build the form:

```
$data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
$entity = new Slot();

$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$form = $this->createForm(SlotType::class, $entity);
    
$form->submit($data, true);
```

zer

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

          ->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
                         "class" => Customer::class
           ]);
```

The form I use to submit this data uses an `EntityType` form type, but it seems it can't recognize the data posted for the `customer` field and tells me that the value is not valid for this field. Do I need to preprocess the data in the controller to populate my entity with associated entities? Or is there a way to attach dataTransformers to the `SlotType` to populate the form with *valid* data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DTO with properties (slotTypeName and customerId), the form will be easier and after the validation you use this DTO to build your entities

Comment: Thanks! It looks like you are talking about API Platform tools, but I'm using a "plain" Symfony with FosRestBundle.

Comment: No, DTO is a concept in all languages, and the validation is done by Symfony Validator, you don't need any library for this, just Symfony.
I don't know about FosRestBundle, never used it.
But Form is from Symfony and you can resolve your problem without FosRestBundle.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering and sorry for having misunderstood your point. Finally found a solution with a FormType taking values such as ["id"=>43] and returning corresponding entity with the type passed as parameter for the field.